# Solving the 1D Heat Equation on [a,b] rather than [0,L]

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, homogeneous-equation, linear-pde, sturm-liouville

## Solve the 1D Heat Equation on $x \in [a,b]$

$$ \frac{\partial ^2 T}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$$
$$ T(a,t) = T(b,t) = 0,        T(x,0) = T_0(x) $$

Now, I know that we should actually just be able to consider the solution for $T(x-a,t)$, basically making the problem the standard 1D heat equation with homogeneous boundaries on $[0,L]$ rather than $[a,b]$, but I was just playing around with the $[a,b]$ case, and arrived at something which I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

### Separating Variables

Separating variables as $T(x,t)=X(x)\Gamma(t)$ gives the standard equations:

$$X''+ \lambda_n ^2 X = 0$$
$$\Gamma' + \alpha \lambda_n ^2 \Gamma = 0$$

Where I am using the "prime" notation loosely even though they represent derivatives with respect to two different variables.

Solving these of course gives:

$$ X(x) = C_1 \cos(\lambda_n x) + C_2 \sin( \lambda_n x) $$
$$ \Gamma(t) = C_3 e^{-\alpha \lambda_n ^2 t} $$

### Possible Mistake

Here is where I feel I am making a mistake. I apply the boundary conditions getting:

$$ T(a,t)=X(a)\Gamma(t)=0 \Rightarrow X(a)=0 $$
Same thing for B getting $X(b) = 0$

Then applying the conditions to the solution:

$$0=C_1 \cos(\lambda_n a) + C_2 \sin( \lambda_n a) $$
$$0=C_1 \cos(\lambda_n b) + C_2 \sin( \lambda_n b) $$

If we solve for $ C_1 = - C_2 \tan(\lambda_n a) $, then we can plug back into the bottom equation and get:

$$ 0 = -C_2 \tan(\lambda_n a) \cos(\lambda_n b) + C_2 \sin(\lambda_n b) $$
Giving the eigenvalues after some manipulation and $C_2$ dividing out as:
$$ \tan(\lambda_n a) = \tan(\lambda_n b) $$

Finally, with $C_2$ and $C_3$ being absorbed to a single constant $C_n$, ignoring the $\lambda_0=0$ trivial eigenvalue, and plugging in the above expression for $C_1$ in terms of $C_2$ into the general solution we have:

$$ T(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n (\sin(\lambda_n x) - \tan(\lambda_n a)\cos(\lambda_n x)) e^{-\alpha \lambda_n^2 t} $$

Now here, I tried to use the solution to the $x$ equation to get the constant $C_n$ using orthogonality like one would normally do. The Sturm-Liouville problem has the standard inner product as well. The only thing that should be different is the bounds.

$$ <f,g> = \int_{a}^b f(x)g(x)dx $$

The orthogonal set of functions for the Sturm-Liouville problem should be $\sin(\lambda_n x) -\tan(\lambda_n a)\cos(\lambda_n x)$ right? Because I try carrying out the integral:

$$ \int_{a}^b (\sin(\lambda_n x) -\tan(\lambda_n a)\cos(\lambda_n x))(\sin(\lambda_m x) -\tan(\lambda_m a)\cos(\lambda_m x)) dx $$

But, this does not give me identically $0$ for $n \neq m$. I tried doing the integration out on paper (messy but doable), and nothing stuck out as making this $0$ for different eigenvalues. I even checked on Desmos by numerically calculating some eigenvalues for a given $a$ and $b$ and then numerically integrating. Even to three decimal places, the precision error cannot account for how far these values were from $0$. So my main question is, where is my mistake? Is it...

1. This actually is not a valid Sturm-Liouville problem in this form for some reason, thus the functions are not orthogonal?
2. I'm using the wrong functions for orthogonality, or I have made an algebra error somewhere?
3. The inner product is actually $0$ and I made a mistake in the calculation?

I can't see why this is not a valid Sturm-Liouville problem, so the functions should be orthogonal. And if it isn't why? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When doing such stuff I usually take a small python program, truncate the series and check my formulas numerically. To me this is far less arduous than agonizing over formulas with pencil and paper.

Comment: Did you determine what values $\lambda_n$ can take?  You should find that integral is zero, assuming that $\lambda_n$ and $\lambda_m$ are indeed eigenvalues.

Comment: @messenger I used a graphing calculator to calculate the first few eigenvalues for select values of a and b to three decimal places. I then plugged them into the integral and numerically calculated it and did not get anywhere close to 0. By "values they can take," do you mean just solutions to that tangent transcendental equation? Or is there some other restriction I am missing? I am neglecting negative values and 0.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks this is interesting. But this actually is just a last-minute rerouting to the solution which one would get using $T(x-a,t)$. I am more interested in where my mistake is in doing it this long way and why it is that this inner product doesn’t seem to show these two functions are orthogonal when they should in fact be.

Comment: Maybe start by looking at your numerical values of $\lambda$.  Are they they the same as the $n\pi/(b-a)$ (for whatever values of $a$ and $b$ you've used)?  If not, that's where your error is.  If they are, then the error is in your evaluation of the integral.

Answer (score -1):

It's not hard to see that the solutions of $X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0$ subject to $X(a)=X(b)=0$ are
$$
              X_n(x)=\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}n\pi\right),  n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$The corresponding values of $\lambda$ are
$$
           \lambda_n = \frac{n^2\pi^2}{(b-a)^2}, n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
And the corresponding solutions $\Gamma$ are
$$
                \Gamma_n(t)=\exp\left(-\alpha\frac{n^2\pi^2}{(b-a)^2}t\right).
$$
You have not simplified your solutons enough to make the orthogonality conditions easy to see.